# compile html with javascript and dump it to file

Tags: javascript, html

I have html with javascript code that modifies the html and prints data, 
and I want to dump this page to a file.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<h1>This is a heading one </h1>");
document.write("<p>This is a paragraph.</p>");
document.write("<p>This is another paragraph.</p>");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a heading two </h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

output.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<h1>This is a heading one </h1>");
document.write("<p>This is a paragraph.</p>");
document.write("<p>This is another paragraph.</p>");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a heading one </h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a heading two </h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I think I need something like html+ java script engine .. browser with command line interface so I can call a page and then dump its output to file ..
any ideas??... any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you need this for?

Comment: You cant - you cannot access the clients filesystem using JavaScript, why are you trying to do this ?

Comment: I would do it on server side with PHP for instance. Would it be possible to use PHP on the server in your case?

Comment: i need to for pdfjs system (online javascipt reader using javascript) .. this system will convert pdf using javascript at client sude ,, and i need to do all this process at server side so client only get final html page

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to do it a few times manually you can use IE 9 Dev tools. in IE 9, you can do F12, then Ctrl+S to save the file to the desired location.

Comment: ... or Opera or Chrome or Firefox or Safari ... well, any browser with dev tools. IE9 would actually have been my last suggestion. You forgot to mention that - in IE only - he would need to update the view of the dev tools after pressing F12 by using the little reload icon (not the one for the website)